# how to redirect to the same page after loging in from that page in cakephp 3.0

Tags: redirect, cakephp-3.0

this is my login method in UsersController.php

```
 public function login()
 {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        $auth = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($auth) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($auth);

            //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'index']);
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid credentials.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
 }
```

In AppController.php

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)                                  
{
    /*if($this->here != '/users'){
        $this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', $this->here);
        } */

    $this->Auth->allow(['controller' => 'Blogs','action' => 'index', 'view']);

}
```

I am new to cakephp. please someone help me. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my controller

```
public function login()
{
    //print_r($this->request->data);
    echo  $lasturl=Router::url( $this->here, true );                                //login from view page starts here  
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        $auth = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($auth) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($auth);

            $this->redirect($this->request->data['lasturl']);
            //return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'index']);
             //return     $this->redirect($this->request->session()->read($lasturl));
        }
    }                                                                           
    $this->set(compact('user'));
}
```

this is my view file

```
<div class="login_comment">
<?= $this->Flash->render('auth') ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Users', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login')));
?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Please Login to Comment for this Post') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->input('lasturl',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$lasturl)) ?>
    </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add loginRedirect Auth component config in AppController.php

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'authorize' => ['Controller'], // Added this line
            'loginRedirect' => [
                'controller' =>Blogs',
                'action' => 'index'
            ]
]);
```

It should work now.

fOR details you can check 
[Auth config](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout)

Comment: hi alimon karim thanks for your answer. However what i am looking for is i want to redirect to url from where i am logging in and also i have found the way and i have posted

Comment: Your question should be " how to redirect last url ", however congrats you have solved it.